# return Promise chain inside Promise then

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I want to fetch API using axios that return array list of objectId. After I get the list objectId I want to fetch the detail of the object using promise

I think of something like this

```
var objectDetail = [];

axios.get('apiendpoint/')
.then((response) => {
  var listOfObjectId = response.data;
  var chain = Promise.resolve()
  for (var objectId of listOfObjectId) {
    chain = chain.then(axios.get(`apiendpoint/${objectId}`)
      .then((response) => {
        objectDetail.push(response.data);
      })
    );
  }
  return chain;
}).then((chain) => {
  console.log(chain);
  return chain;
})
```

the code above returns undefined, the promise chain object is not passed to `then` method call. Is my approach wrong or am I missing something? thank you

Here are some stack I have read, might be related:

- [How to loop dynamically over multiple promises in a for loop while using fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48414827/how-to-loop-dynamically-over-multiple-promises-in-a-for-loop-while-using-fetch)
- [Creating a promise chain in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955463/creating-a-promise-chain-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: Why you dont use the `promise.all()` documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @Mederic I kind of confused, how can I dynamically create a promise from the objectId's of 'apiendpoint/' ? can you explain a bit how to solve that with `promise.all()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The promise chain *is* being passed to the final `.then`, but the promise chain *isn't returning anything*: see your

```
.then((response) => {
  objectDetail.push(response.data);
})
```

That function doesn't return anything. If you wanted to use `objectDetail` at the end of the chain without referencing the outer variable, `return` it as well:

```
.then((response) => {
  objectDetail.push(response.data);
  return objectDetail;
})
```

But note that

```
}).then((chain) => {
  console.log(chain);
  return chain;
})
```

is a bit redundant - unless you're only doing that in order to `log` the result, better just to leave it off entirely.

Your code would be clearer if you used `Promise.all` instead:

```
axios.get('apiendpoint/')
  .then(({ data }) => Promise.all(
    data.map(objectId => (axios.get(`apiendpoint/${objectId}`)
      .then(res => res.data)
    ))
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't **fulfill** a promise with a promise. If you return a promise from within a `then( onfulfilled)` handler, promise code waits for the returned promise to be *settled* before resolving or rejecting the next promise in a chain  with the success or failure value of the returned  promise.

So

```
//...
  return chain;
}).then((chain) => {
  console.log(chain);
  return chain;
})
```

is confusing - the `chain` promise returned in the first line is not passed to the next `then` handler. What is passed is `fulfilled` value of the last promise in `chain` after it completes successfully. However, since handlers within `chain` don't explicitly return a value, this will be `undefined`.

Options include:

- For debugging purposes, optionally log the value of `chain` after constructing it in its entirety before returning `chain` from the first then handler.
- Ignore the actual value passed to the final `then` success handler and use it being called to indicate `objectDetail` contains valid data, or
- Create `objectDetail` in the first then handler and return it from promise handlers added to `chain` during construction.

  ```
  axios.get('apiendpoint/')
  .then((response) => {
      var listOfObjectId = response.data;
      var objectDetail = [];
      var chain = Promise.resolve()
      for (var objectId of listOfObjectId) {
          chain = chain.then(axios.get(`apiendpoint/${objectId}`)
          .then((response) => {
              objectDetail.push(response.data);
              return objectDetail; // return details array
          });
      }
      return chain;
  })
  .then( objectDetail) => {
      // process objectDetail
  })
  .catch(err=> console.log(err););
  ```

The method above processes detail requests sequentially. It could be  rewriten using `Promise.all` for detail requests to be issued in parallel.